# Modify build-in Object prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

```
String.prototype = new Number();
console.log(String.prototype.__proto__ === Number.prototype);//return false
```

why i cant change the prototype chain of bulid-in Object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the `prototype` property of built-in constructors<sup>1</sup> is non-writable (also non-configurable and non-enumerable).

See the property attributes:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(String, 'prototype');

/*
configurable: false,
enumerable: false,
writable: false
*/
```

This is described in each built-in constructor, for the [`String.prototype`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.5.3.1) property see :

> 15.5.3.1 String.prototype
>
> ...
>
> This property has the attributes { [[Writable]]: false, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: false }.

<sup>1</sup>: by *"built-in constructor"* I refer to the [constructor functions defined on the global object](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1.4): `String`, `Number`, `Boolean`, `Object`, `Array`, `Function`, `Date`, `RegExp`, `Error` (and other [`NativeError` types](http://es5.github.com/#x15.11.6)).